# Add constraint in IB by keyboard only

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints

I want to add constraints more quickly by using keyboard only. Look at my screen example. [image]

I want to add constraints to leading (16), trailing (16), bottom (20). How can I do this without click on 3 lines?

Comment: there also a way to mouse's right click+dragging line to superview from subview, assuming that you haven't tried

Comment: Off Topic: The Interface Builder is a click tool. I would suggest to build your UIs in Code.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard: TAB->DELETE->TAB->DELETE->TAB->DELETE->TAB->ENTER

[image]